# React-to-Print Issue: Updated State not Reflected in Print Output

Tags: reactjs, react-to-print

I am using react-to-print to print bills in my billing-system app. I've encountered an issue where one of the states (`rows`), containing a list of bills, is updated just before printing to consolidate the items entered in the bill. Although the state is updated successfully, the print output does not reflect the changes.

**MyComponent.jsx**

```js
const handleBillPrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => printableRef.current,
    onAfterPrint: () => handleBillSave("success") && handleBillReset(),
    onBeforeGetContent: () => setRows(consolidateItemRows(rows))
})
```

I would appreciate any insights or solutions on why the updated state is not being reflected in the print output. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that state updates are asynchronous. This means that the `setRows` call does not complete immediately. To fix this, you need to pass a Promise to `onBeforeGetContent` and then detect that the rows have updated to finally resolve it. There is a [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print#setting-state-in-onbeforegetcontent) section (reproduced below) about this.

> **Setting state in `onBeforeGetContent`**
> Recall that setting state is asynchronous. As such, you need to pass a Promise and wait for the state to update.
>
> ```
> const [isPrinting, setIsPrinting] = useState(false);
> const printRef = useRef(null);
>
> // We store the resolve Promise being used in `onBeforeGetContent` here
> const promiseResolveRef = useRef(null);
>
> // We watch for the state to change here, and for the Promise resolve to be available
> useEffect(() => {
>   if (isPrinting && promiseResolveRef.current) {
>     // Resolves the Promise, letting `react-to-print` know that the DOM updates are completed
>     promiseResolveRef.current();
>   }
> }, [isPrinting]);
>
> const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
>   content: () => printRef.current,
>   onBeforeGetContent: () => {
>     return new Promise((resolve) => {
>       promiseResolveRef.current = resolve;
>       setIsPrinting(true);
>     });
>   },
>   onAfterPrint: () => {
>     // Reset the Promise resolve so we can print again
>     promiseResolveRef.current = null;
>     setIsPrinting(false);
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> Note: for Class components, just pass the resolve to the callback for `this.setState`: `this.setState({ isPrinting: false }, resolve)`